# Android emulator - unable to load driver

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator

Running on Ubuntu, I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  55
  Current serial number in output stream:  54
```

Platform-tools is the latest.

Emulator image uses `https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86_64-24_r08.zip` and it's on Android N.

*Update (Dec 2, 2016):* @Sébastien's solution no longer works but gives:

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
failed to create drawable
getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not create GLES 2.x Pbuffer!
Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!
Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
emulator: WARNING: ./android/metrics/metrics_reporter.cpp:142: Failed to get a writable, unused path for metrics. Tried: /home/me/.android/avd/metrics/metrics.17386.yogibear
```

If I disable GPU based rendering and switch to software based GL graphics, there is this runtime error:

```
Firebase API initialization failure.
               DeadSystemException: The system died; earlier logs will point to the root cause
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.whatever.mobile, PID: 4501
                  DeadSystemException: The system died; earlier logs will point to the root cause
```

Comment: Are you running Yakkety on 'bare metal' box (i.e. not virtual)?
Have you has tried to rebuild/reinstall Intel VGA drivers (kernel modules)?
Yakkety was released just a few days ago (as of 2016-10-16), you may need to wait a little

Comment: Yes, bare metal. I didn't mess with the kernel modules as all other apps work fine.

Comment: try to rebuild kernel modules (as i965 and swrast are is definitely point to Intel VGA "drivers", could be AE mistake though).
You should google (within askubuntu, as an option) on the option of kernel module rebuild. 
Not my sphere of expertise for your case unfortunately.
It can be Android emulator just does not supports Yakkety yet.
Still, I'm almost sure it has nothing about specific OS support (Android is not that aware of it) but more about lack of specific kernel modules

Comment: My pardon I cannot forward you to some specific direction, yet I hope you've got the general idea on it. (AVD is based on QEmu, but I believe you're aware of it)

Comment: I feel you do use AVD from AndroidStudio (as I had always did).
Rebuilding one from scratch may resolve the issue (but I cannot help you with it), or waiting for few days while it's rebuilt by maintainers can help.
Yakkety was released less then 5 days ago, after all )

Comment: And, ... It seems to me that your question should be better moved to superuser.com ...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Had the same issue and my fix was to set the following env variable:

> export ANDROID_EMULATOR_USE_SYSTEM_LIBS=1

In my case I put it in ~/.bashrc.
With that being sent I start emulator as usual, i.e. from command line:

> $ emulator -avd Nexus_4_API_23

Looks like it's a common well-known problem tracked in Android bug tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=197254

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04, I had to put `export ANDROID_EMULATOR_USE_SYSTEM_LIBS=1` in `~/.profile` in order for Android Studio to pick it up.

Answer (score 9):

I've just face the same error, and simply deleting `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/lib64/libstdc++/*` worked for me. libstdc++ version shipped with 16.10 (6.0.22) is greater than the one shipped with the sdk tools (6.0.18), and I suppose it creates conflicts with other libraries.

Comment: This no longer works, updated my question. Any new workaround?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is related to l**ibstdc++.so.6** go to Android SDK and can be resolved with the following command:

```
cd ~/...../sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6_OLD
ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6
```

Credit: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=197254#c43

Comment: This does not fix it. Still the emulator kills itself with the error `getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not create GLES 2.x Pbuffer!` Need to switch to Software base rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I had been struggling with this pretty much, the answer is correct, it's just the application method that took me time to figure out :

(as Root) I have run : locate libstdc++.so.6

Then with the result list of the current lib WITH VERSION and LOCATION
I applied the mv/rm on the ones shipped with Android SDK (~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6 in my case), and then made a link from the system ones (/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 OR /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 OR /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6 depend on your system)