# Android Emulator not Launching on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, ubuntu-17.04

I am using Android Studio 3.0.1 on Ubuntu 17.04.When I am trying to run app on virtual device following error messages popups.
    Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so

```
Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing

Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: i965

Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so

Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing

Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: i965

Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so

Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

Emulator: X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)

Emulator: Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)

Emulator: Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)

Emulator: Value in failed request:  0x0

Emulator: Serial number of failed request:  39

Emulator: Current serial number in output stream:  40

Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please give me some help to overcome these errors.

Comment: Try the answers from this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/867081/android-studio-buggy-after-upgrade-to-16-10

Comment: Thanks , your link helped me to solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android emulator - unable to load driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066007/android-emulator-unable-to-load-driver)

Answer (score 0):

Ok looks like in the recent android studio update, Google used a **libstdc++** incompatible with the Intel driver installed on the system.

```
[dustin@dustin-linux:tools]$ LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose ./emulator
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/xorg/modules/dri/tls/i965_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/xorg/modules/dri/i965_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/xorg/modules/dri/i965_dri.so failed (/home/dustin/opt/android-studio/sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/xorg/modules/dri/i965_dri.so))
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/xorg/modules/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/xorg/modules/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/xorg/modules/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/home/dustin/opt/android-studio/sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/xorg/modules/dri/swrast_dri.so))
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  49
  Current serial number in output stream:  48
emulator: ERROR: You did not specify a virtual device name, and the system
directory could not be found.

If you are an Android SDK user, please use '@<name>' or '-avd <name>'
to start a given virtual device (use -list-avds to print available ones).

Otherwise, follow the instructions in -help-disk-images to start the emulator
```

> so basically I renamed the
>   "android-studio/sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6" file so it
>   has to use the system ones ... that basically does the trick – for me.

originally posted [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=213192)