# Android Studio 3.0 emulator does not start

Tags: linux, android-studio, android-emulator

Android Studio emulator can't start in Kali Linux. The error I get is:

> 25/12/17 3:01 AM  Gradle sync started
>
> 3:01 AM   Project setup started
>
> 3:01 AM   Gradle sync finished in 1s 333ms (from cached state)
>
> 3:02 AM   * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
>
> 3:02 AM   Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
>
> 3:02 AM   Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing
>
> 3:02 AM    Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
>
> 3:02 AM   Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
>
> 3:02 AM   Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing
>
> 3:02 AM   Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
>
> 3:02 AM   Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
>
> 3:02 AM    Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
>
> 3:02 AM   Emulator: X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer
>   parameter out of range for operation)
>
> 3:02 AM   Emulator: Major opcode of failed request:  156 (GLX)
>
> 3:02 AM   Emulator: Minor opcode of failed request:  24
>   (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
>
> 3:02 AM   Emulator: Value in failed request:  0x0
>
> 3:02 AM    Emulator: Serial number of failed request:  68
>
> 3:02 AM    Emulator: Current serial number in output stream:  69
>
> 3:02 AM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
>
> 3:02 AM   * daemon started successfully
>
> 3:02 AM   Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> 3:02 AM    Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
>
> 3:02 AM    Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing
>
> 3:02 AM   Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
>
> 3:02 AM    Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
>
> 3:02 AM   Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing
>
> 3:02 AM   Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
>
> 3:02 AM    Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
>
> 3:02 AM   Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
>
> 3:02 AM    Emulator: X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer
>   parameter out of range for operation)
>
> 3:02 AM   Emulator: Major opcode of failed request:  156 (GLX)
>
> 3:02 AM    Emulator: Minor opcode of failed request:  24
>   (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
>
> 3:02 AM    Emulator: Value in failed request:  0x0
>
> 3:02 AM    Emulator: Serial number of failed request:  68
>
> 3:02 AM   Emulator: Current serial number in output stream:  69
>
> 3:02 AM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
>
> 3:03 AM   Gradle build finished in 16s 582ms

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android emulator - unable to load driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066007/android-emulator-unable-to-load-driver)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like, in some android studio update, google used a libstdc++ incompatible with the intel driver installed on the system.

Edit your .profile using your favorite text editor

vim ~/.profile
Append this at the end of the file

```
export ANDROID_EMULATOR_USE_SYSTEM_LIBS=1
```

---

If it doesn't work try installing lib64stdc++ and mesa-utils libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install lib64stdc++6 mesa-utils
```

and making a symlink from the system libstdc++ to the android studio one:

```
cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++/
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
```