# Android Studio 3 emulator fails on Linux Mint

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, android-emulator

I have a new installation of Android Studio 3 on Linux Mint.  When trying to run on an emulator, it fails with the following errors in the log:

> 7:00 PM   Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
>
> 7:00 PM   Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing
>
> 7:00 PM   Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
>
> 7:00 PM   Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
>
> 7:00 PM   Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
>
> 7:00 PM   Emulator: X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer
>   parameter out of range for operation)
>
> 7:00 PM   Emulator: Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
>
> 7:00 PM   Emulator: Minor opcode of failed request:  24
>   (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
>
> 7:00 PM   Emulator: Value in failed request:  0x0
>
> 7:00 PM   Emulator: Serial number of failed request:  58
>
> 7:00 PM   Emulator: Current serial number in output stream:  59
>
> 7:00 PM   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

It looks like it is trying to use the default X.Org Nouveau display driver.  However, I am using the NVIDIA binary driver 384.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio 3.0 emulator does not start](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47964257/608639) and [Many errors while opening the emulator. How to fix those errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50086877/608639)

Answer (score 0):

look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42187204
Edit the virtual device and change "Graphics" to "Software - GLES 1.1"