# Many errors while opening the emulator. How to fix those errors?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

05:48 PM    Emulator: emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'Qt event loop'. No response for 15002 ms

05:50 PM    Gradle build finished in 3m 5s 410ms

05:52 PM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code 255

05:57 PM    adb refused request: closed

05:57 PM    Failed to start monitoring emulator-5554

05:57 PM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0

06:04 PM    Emulator: emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'Qt event loop'. No response for 15002 ms

06:05 PM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

06:18 PM    Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger

06:20 PM    Can't bind to local 8617 for debugger

06:25 PM    Emulator: emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'Qt event loop'. No response for 15001 ms

06:26 PM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your Android Emulator to the latest version. These bugs were fixed in the [recent revisions](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator).

Comment: I have installed the android studio today.

Comment: What is your Android Emulator version?

Comment: version - 27.1.12