# android studio emulator libGl error

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Created a new device using android API 27, google inc. and x86.
It's giving me following errors on launching. How to resolve this?

```
12:01 PM    Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
12:01 PM    Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing
12:01 PM    Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
12:01 PM    Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
12:01 PM    Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing
12:01 PM    Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
12:01 PM    Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
12:01 PM    Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
12:01 PM    Emulator: X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation.
12:01 PM    Emulator: Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
12:01 PM    Emulator: Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
12:01 PM    Emulator: Value in failed request:  0x0
12:01 PM    Emulator: Serial number of failed request:  64
12:01 PM    Emulator: Current serial number in output stream:  65
12:01 PM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android emulator - unable to load driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066007/android-emulator-unable-to-load-driver)

Answer (score -3):

Here is a useful guide .Use it

> https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html

Comment: Can you exactly tell where I should look for my problem?
It's a pretty long documentation and I'm new to Android Studio. 
Thanks for the help though.